# How do I add the java icon and lineup text with input?

Tags: java, swing

So I'm trying to get the same result, according to this picture:

[image: halp.png]

I'm trying to make the bottom 2 look like the upper 2.
So the first problem is that I don't get the java icon in the title.
The second problem is that "Some text:" isn't lined with the input box.

Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Some Text:", "Dialog",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if(input != null)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Value entered: " + input, "Message box", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    else
        System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Where did the first image come from? Looks like it's manually created, rather than just the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` option.

Comment: Its an assignment i got. The functionalty wasnt a problem, but the layout is really bugging me.

Comment: I don't have time to put together an actual answer, but look into creating your own JFrames/layouts. If I have time later I'll throw together an example if no one else has.

Comment: Thanks alot, im already trying with some frames and panels, but i just cant get it to look like that. I will keep trying though

Comment: I still didnt manage to get it look like that.. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can add Swing Component to `JOptionPane`. So why not creating a custom panel containing a `JLabel` and `JTextFeild` with layout i.e., `FlowLayout` and add that panel to JOptionPane using

```
   JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog
   (
        frame, // main window frame
        customPanel, // custom panel containing the label and textFeild
        "My Panel with Text Feild", // Title
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, // with OK and CANCEL button
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE 

   );
```

**A minimal working example:**

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class CustomPanel extends JPanel
{
    JLabel lab;
    JTextField txtField;

    public CustomPanel() {

        lab = new JLabel("Some Text: ");
        txtField = new JTextField(20);

        add(lab);
        add(txtField);

    }

    public String getText()
    {
       return txtField.getText();
    }

}

public class JOptionPaneDemo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CustomPanel inputPane = new CustomPanel();
               int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, inputPane, "Demo" ,JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
               if(value == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Value Entered: "+inputPane.getText(), "Demo", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
               }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Tutorial resource:** [How to make Dialogue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: I have been trying all day, and it doesnt seem to take in my frame object. I just can't get it to work. Maybe im doing something wrong, im pretty new to programming

Comment: frame is actually JFrame inside which you are working. If it doesn't take, try setting with `null` first.

Comment: It still wont take JFrame, and if i set it to null the Java icon top left wont show up. I tried some different things, but i still can't get it to look like the top picture. Frustrating.. bla :)

Comment: Thx alot that helped me on my main issue! :) Thx again

Comment: :) congrats. glad to hear that.